# What is difference between GeometryService areasAndLengths method and Measurement widget in ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

What's the difference between the GeometryService areasAndLengths method and the Measurement widget to make a caculation in the ArcGIS JS API? Accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think these are comparable.

The [Areas and Lengths](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html) Operation on a Geometry Service, is a web service that can be used to get the Areas and Lengths of an Arbitrary set of polygons in any arbitrary spatial references.

The [Measurement widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/measurement.html) is a dojo widget that is used in the ESRI JSAPI to draw shapes on the map, and get the area/length etc. If the Map is not in  Web Mercator or geographic projection, it will need a geometry service to project or simplify geometries.

Comment: Thx, in my opinion, both of them could get the measurement work down in a web application, so in this situation, they have no different, is it right?

Comment: @ZhangYang:It's like saying that a super-market and a farm is basically the same, since you get vegetables and meat at both places. The Measurement Widget is useful in certain situations while the Geometry service is much more flexible and can be used for many different things.

Comment: All right, great example, Thank u very much. The Measurement is suit for the certain polygon, and Geometry Service is more flexible, I think I have had a concept about this.